# On image hover - Mouse is showing as text icon?

Tags: html, css

Hover over the currency signs (which clicked, change the pricing currency) and a text icon "I" shows instead of the mouse. How do I fix this?

Explanatory screen shot can be found at: [here](http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/hover-text-icon-shows.jpg)

The page itself is found: [here](http://www.workbooks.com/pricing)

Posting image as code as **not enough rep to post images**, if someone could edit that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "cursor:pointer" in css rules:

```
#currency-switch span {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert this code somewhere in your css files,

```
#currency-switch > span {cursor:pointer}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cursor:pointer` in css rules:

```
 #currency-switch span {cursor: pointer;margin-left: 10px;}
```

[See also](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your cursor on hover for specific elements. There are a lot of cursor types for me to paste them all here, so take a look ---> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: posting a link to tell them to go and look it up themselves is not an answer. You should just leave this as a comment

Comment: Totally, and he'll end up with 3 answers telling him to change it to cursor: pointer; because that's such an informative answer.

Comment: Yeah I agree there is no need to post the same answer 3 times, but at least they have actually provided a solution

Comment: Thanks all the same, as I never knew there were so many different cursor types!